# css locatorを用いてtextを部分一致で返せますか

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

ex)

```
<a class="sample" id="sample_id" href="../">sample text</a>
```

下記のように、xpathを指定して要素を取得することはcssとxpathのどちらでもできます。

```
exist?(xpath: '//a[@class="sample"]')
exist?(css: 'a[class="sample"]') # exist?(css: 'a.sample')
```

こういった時にtextを指定したいということがあると思いますが、css selectorを用いてtextを指定することは可能なのでしょうか。

```
# xpath
exist?(xpath: '//a[text()[contains(.,"sample text")]]')
# css
...?
```

Comment: CSSの`:contains()`セレクターは`performance and over-selection issues`によりCSS3から外されているようですね。 [本家SOの関連する質問への回答](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781141/why-doesnt-the-selector-h3nth-child1containsa-work/4781167#4781167) / [css3-selectors/#content-selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

出来ないと思います。
似た物に[jQueryの :contains セレクタ](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)がありますが、素のCSSにはこういった物は(今のところは)ありません。